# Embedding OpenLayers map as an SVG foreignObject causes map to appear on top of all other SVG elements regardless of SVG element ordering

Tags: javascript, html, svg, openlayers

I'm trying to use OpenLayers map within SVG in a situation where I'd like SVG elements to appear on top of/in front of the map.  I've created a simple test example based on the OpenLayers tutorial, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Working with Openlayers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- Openlayers CSS file-->

    <style type="text/css">
      #map{
        width:100%;
        height:600px;
      }
    </style>
    <!--Basic styling for map div, 
    if height is not defined the div will show up with 0 px height  -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="800" height="500">
      <rect width="600" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,255,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
      <foreignObject height="300" id="_MapPOC.7-foreignObject" width="600" y="100" x="100">
        <div id="map">
          <!-- Your map will be shown inside this div-->
        </div>
      </foreignObject>
      <rect width="600" height="300" x="200" y="200" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
    </svg>
  </body>
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Openlayesr JS fIle -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Our map file -->
</html>
```

In this example, the first (cyan) rectangle should appear at the back, then the map (foreign object) should appear in the middle, and the second (yellow) rectangle should appear on top.

However, when I view the page, the map appears over the top of both the cyan and the yellow rectangle.

If I change the content of the foreign object to some regular HTML instead of the map, then the ordering is working as expected.  Only when the OpenLayers map is embedded within the foreign object is it appearing above everything else, despite the ordering of the SVG elements.

I would like to know if someone knows how I can make the map appear correctly ordered in the SVG elements?

I'm using Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Seems to be a Chrome bug. You should report it to [their bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) unless someone already has.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the question, but an effort to put the code to be runnable. It demonstrates the problem better.

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-74.006,40.712]), // Coordinates of New York
          zoom: 7 //Initial Zoom Level
        })
      });
```

```css
 <style type="text/css">
  #map{
   width:100%;
   height:600px;
  }
 </style>
```

```html
<head>
 <title>Working with Openlayers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
 <div id="map3">
  <!-- Your map will NOT be created inside this div-->
 </div>
    <svg width="800" height="500">
      <rect width="600" height="300" style="fill:rgb(0,255,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
      <foreignObject height="300" id="_MapPOC.7-foreignObject" width="600" y="100" x="100">
        <div id="map">
          <!-- Your map will be created inside this div-->
        </div>
      </foreignObject>
      <rect width="600" height="300" x="200" y="200" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
    </svg>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```